# IntelliJ IDEA Alias for language recognition

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the project with language not supported with any IntelliJ IDEA plugins. The syntax equals `C` language, but files had extension `*.mq5`.

Can I set an alias for `*.mq5` files to IDEA recognize them as `*.c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Go to: **Settings > Editor > File Types**. Choose C/C++ and in **File name patterns** add *.mq5

However it is better to use JetBrain C++ IDE - [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) (there is no free version, I think) or [Eclipse for C/C++](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-03/r/eclipse-ide-cc-developers).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*.mq5 is an MQL language extension, there is a third party plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9291-mql-idea

Comment: unfortunately this plugin works only for `*.mq4`. Question not only about `*.mq*` it's about aliases for language recognition.